# Combine two Regular Expresiions

Tags: java, regex

I already Have an Regex like below which matches the below given values.

```
^(.*)\s+PER\s+(.*?)(?:\sIn\s*(.+?))?(?:\s*DEAD.*)?$**
```

1. **5** PER **Sample**
2. **5** PER **Request**
3. **5** PER **Batch**
4. **5** PER **Plate**
5. **5** PER **Empty Well** In **Column**
6. **9.0** PER **Sample** DEAD VOLUME 9

Now I need this regex to also check for the below given value

```
DataField = Value(9.0 PER Sample DEAD VOLUME 9)
```

I have tried an Reg Ex like below

```
^(.*)\s+[=]\s+(.*?)\s+[(](.*)[)]$
```

Which would do this.

```
Input : DataField = Value (5 PER Sample)
```

Current Grouped Output:

```
Group 1: DataField
Group 2: Value
Group 3: 5 PER Sample
```

Now I need an which would combine the existing two regex to group the input like below (highlighted).

1. **DataField** = **Value** ( **9.0** PER **Sample** DEAD VOLUME 9 )
2. **DataField** = **Value** ( **9.0** PER **Sample**)
3. **DataField** = **Value** ( **5** PER **Empty Well** In **Column**)
4. **9.0** PER **Sample** DEAD VOLUME 9
5. **5** PER **Sample**
6. **5** PER **Request**
7. **5** PER **Batch**
8. **5** PER **Plate**
9. **5** PER **Empty Well** In **Column**

Could someone please help in achieving this?

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/HsJ653/1).

Comment: You need a different approach to this. Something involving `(\S+)\s+`

Comment: The problem is what comes between `PER <here> In <here>` has nested options. Using `.+?` is a reach. I'd say this is undo-able without making it much more form based. Requires specific options. You can see what I mean if you split on spaces. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Combined regex:

```
^(?<datafield>.*)\s+[=]\s+(?<value>.*?)\s+[(](?<number>.*)\s+PER\s+(?<something>.*?)(?:\sIn\s*(?<location>.+?))?(?:\s*DEAD.*)?[)]$
```

Now you need to make first part optional:

```
^((?<datafield>.*)\s+[=]\s+(?<value>.*?)\s+[(])?(?<number>.*)\s+PER\s+(?<something>.*?)(?:\sIn\s*(?<location>.+?))?(?:\s*DEAD.*)?[)]?$
```

Comment: Could you please update replace sections like <datafield>, <value> with something like this (.*)...I tried doing it and failed in it....I am bad at regex.

Comment: `?<datafield>` is a named group in java regexps starting from Java 7. You then can get group by names (e.g. datafield etc.) which is more convenient then referencing them by numbers. see documentation for Pattern : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?:(\w+)\s=\s(\w+)\s\(\s)?([\d.]+(?!$))\s\w+\s(\w+ ?(?!DEAD)\w+) ?\w* ?(?:VOLUME)? ?(\w+)?
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gLjFc3/1/)**